# Testing iPad app on two separate iPads

Tags: ipad, testing

I am developing an iPad/iPhone app in Florida and wish an associate in New York to test it for me. The tester in NY does not have an iMac as they do not perform any development at that location. I just want them to verify the operation at thier location. Is there any way to get my app installed on their device without them having to ship their iPad/iPhone to my location to download software into the unit? Is there any way to wirelessly download development software instead of having to plug it into a Mac? We are going to have many different releases before we are ready to put the app into the app store.

Answer (score 2):

They must have some computer that they sync their iPad with? It doesn't have to be a Mac. It's easy:

1) Get their iPad's UDID

2) Add the UDID to your Ad-Hoc Distribution certificate (see Apple's helpful prompts on the provisioning portal on this gets done)

3) Build.

4) Send your user the .mobileprovision file (resulting from step 2) and the .ipa (your application).

5) They need to drag both files into their iTunes library on their computer, and then have the iPad sync with the machine.

Comment: Great answer, just a note: in the "build" step, make sure the "Active Configuration" in XCode is on "Ad Hoc" and as far as I know you don't need to send the .mobileprovision file separately, but it's doesn't do any harm if you do.

Comment: You're right about Active Configuration. Wrong about .mobileprovision though. The device will end up with with a profile (under Settings->General->Profiles) as a result of the .mobileprovision being synced down to it together with the .ipa. If the profile is not there, the device won't run the app. In fact, even syncing it will fail.